# how can I bring value to main query from subquery

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT top 10 
U.UserId,U.PhoneNumber  from Users U  with(nolock)
inner join ConsumerProfiles CP with(nolock) on CP.ConsumerId=U.UserId
and userId in 
(
select distinct(A.userId), A.CreatedOn from ( select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY createdon asc) AS RowNumber 
from Permissions with(nolock)
where 1=1
and permissionId=5
and Approved=1
)
A where A.RowNumber=1 )
```

I need to add A.createdon to main query (top 10 select query).
How can I add that.

```
SELECT top 10 
U.UserId,U.PhoneNumber,A.createdon
```

like that.

.

Thanks.

Comment: [Stop splattering your code with nolock hints](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Short answer is to join. And using TOP without an order by clause is generally a logic flaw.

Comment: Why `WHERE 1=1`? When does `1` *not* equal `1`? Also, your subquery in the `IN` is return 2 different columns, which will generate an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring the code provided I think something like this would work

```
;with
users_cte(UserId, PhoneNumber) as (
    SELECT top 10 U.UserId, U.PhoneNumber
    from Users U 
         inner join ConsumerProfiles CP on CP.ConsumerId=U.UserId),
permissions_cte(UserId, createdon, RowNumber) as (
    select UserId, createdon, row_number() over (partition by userid order by createdon asc) RowNumber 
    from Permissions
    where 1=1
          and permissionId=5
          and Approved=1)
select
  uc.UserId, uc.PhoneNumber, pc.createdon
from users_cte uc
     join permissions_cte pc on uc.UserId=pc.UserId
where pc.RowNumber=1;
```